# Install Flash Player on IE7/IE8 with Wine

Tags: 14.04, wine, flash, playonlinux, ie

I have to set up IE7 or IE8 with Adobe Flash Player on a Linux machine (to test a very old web application) but I fight with some compatibility Flash problems. I'm using PlayOnLinux on Ubuntu 14.04 and I installed successfully IE with this tool but I tried to install Flash many times without success (from https://helpx.adobe.com/fr/flash-player/kb/archived-flash-player-versions.html).

Using PlayOnLinux is very user-friendly but I concede that Wine is very obscure for me ... Most of my Flash installers crashed and the others who don't, changed nothing : I can't use my web application, everytime it is written that I have to install Adobe Flash Player to see the content.

I read that when Flash is installed you have to add it on extensions modules on IE but nothing is displayed. Do anyone has ever tried such a vintage/weird configuration, or can give me some clues to install Flash properly on IE with wine ?

Cheers

Comment: Maybe if you download and install the file for windows inside wine? Doesn't that work? Just a random guess what I would try... Execute it from inside IE's download list and see what it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved !
I resintall wine only (without PlayOnLinux) and I installed ie8 with winetricks.
I downloaded flashplayer9 and copied it in the wine ie8 folder, executed the flashplayer.exe for windows and launch iexplorer.exe from the .wine/...../IE folder.